# How do I add a new C# solution to my Azure DevOps?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have created a new solution on my local computer. I now want to push it up as a new project in our company Azure DevOps. But All I can find in Visual Studio is a menu item to create a GitHub project.
How do I push it up to create a new project in DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I push it up to create a new project in DevOps?

First, we need to create a new repo on the Azure Devops from the web portal.

Then, if your visual studio version is 2019 and above, there is an option **Clone a repository** when you luanch the Visual Studio:

[image]

Select it and we will jump to another navigation screen:

[image]

After completing this, we can create a new solution to the path we just set or copy the project you created earlier to the path set in the previous step.

If your visual studio version is 2017 and below, we need to open the Team Explorer and connect to the repo we have created, then we create the new solution or copy solution to the local path.

You could refer to the document [Get started with Git in Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitquickstart?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019) for some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can find `Add to Source Control` in the right corner of VS:

[image]

Then you can publish your project:

[image]